# Removing python from usr/bin on Mac OS

Tags: python, macos

My Python installation was broken, so I wanted to uninstall Python and start over. I thought I had wiped all the Python (minus the installations in Systems), but when I run

`which python`

I see

`/usr/bin/python`

I tried just removing the file, but this violates MAC permissions. I could reboot in recovery mode and override, but I'm not sure if I should? Does anyone know if there are problems associated with doing this? Also what exactly is this file?

Comment: Have you tried using the command `sudo rm /usr/bin/python` on the mac terminal?

Comment: “*Also what exactly is this file?*” If you have to ask this, it’s pretty clear you shouldn’t proceed until you understand exactly the implications of doing this.

Comment: If you intend to uninstall python, you can follow the guide [here](https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/5880/python/uninstall). I don't think deleting `/usr/bin/python` would uninstall python completely since it's just a symbolic link

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: yes I've tried sudo rm and sudo rm -rf, it's a violation of MAC protocol so in order to actually remove it I would have to boot in recovery mode

Comment: `/usr/bin/python` and the files in `/System/Library/Frameworks/...` are all part of the basic Python setup that's built into macOS. You should almost never mess with it (and reinstalling it will require reinstalling the OS). Whatever's messed up in your Python installation is almost certainly something that was installed *in addition to* it, and you should be removing that, not the built-in Python files.

Answer (score 0):

This file is not meant to be manually removed. You should uninstall Python because you will probably have whole bunch of binaries and libraries that will need to be removed too. Also, this is probably a symlink so you will need to hunt down all files associated with whatever version it is pointing to.

If you have to remove it manually because your installation is so broken then `sudo rm /usr/bin/python` and a password should work - if by violates MAC permissions you mean the usual permission error `rm: cannot remove '/usr/bin/python': Permission denied"`.

You should not need to boot into recovery mode.

In the future, for all programs that rely on Python, do not run `pip` with elevated permissions (ideally use a virtual environment). It sounds that this is likely the cause of your problem.

Comment: Okay so it was actually a symlink, which points to "../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7". This seems, not good...

Comment: Removing the symlink won't mess with my System installation of python will it? I don't know how this got here but it seems like it might've been the root of my original problems

Comment: The symlink won't be the root of your problem, it likely exists to point to a default version so you can call ``python`` instead of ``python3``, ``python3.8`` etc this would have been implemented by your installer. Run ``ls -l`` and you will see what it points to. I can't really help you any further as I'm not sure of the reason you believe the installation is broken.